# React Native Linking simultaneously for mail AND sms

Tags: react-native

Is it possible to Linking.openUrl() for both mail and sms ? I'd like my user to choose between those app and prefill information in the body.

`Linking.openURL('mailto:support@example.com?subject=SendMail&body=Description')`
does suggest mail apps

`Linking.openURL('sms:number?body=Description')`
does suggest sms apps

Is there a way to have both app proposed to the user while being prefilled with `Description` ?

Comment: Linking API doesn't provide that option. You need to build UI like 2 buttons for each linking type or dropdown for a user to choose her/his preferred option

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are looking for "Share" functionality.

See the official [React Native Share Docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/share), or this [popular third party library](https://github.com/react-native-share/react-native-share).

Answer (score -1):

**FOR mail**

```
Linking.openURL('mailto:example@example.com?subject=SendMail&body=Description')
```

**FOR sms**

```
Linking.openURL('sms:number?body=yourMessage?subject=SendMail&body=Description')
```

If this information not enough; you should be 3.part package like;

https://github.com/flexible-agency/react-native-email-link

or

React Native Share.